# Why is local qasm simulation taking so long for VQE?

Tags: qiskit, programming, textbook-and-exercises, vqe

I've successfully run the $LiH$ VQE simulation detailed in [Simulating Molecules using VQE](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html) using the `statevector_simulator`, however when attempting to run the same simulation on the `quantum_instance`(detailed in the same section) using the `NoiseModel` for `ibmq_manhattan` the simulation seems to run indefinitely without yielding results.

Is it expected that the `quantum_instance` simulation would be significantly longer ($>100\times$) than the `statevector_simulator` simulation?

Note: I'm using the following optimizer and variational form:

```
optimizer = SPSA(maxiter=100)
var_form = EfficientSU2(qubitOp.num_qubits, entanglement="linear")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statevector simulator is a perfect/ideal simulation. It basically just manipulate the quantum state according to linear algebra. qasm_simulator with or without noise model is a shot based simulation that mimic the behavior of the device.

In other words, you can think of statevector simulator as performing a 1 shot experiment, whereas qasm_simulator is performing multiple shots simulation, hence it will take longer.

Note that as you go up in size, statevector simulation is not ideal... as you will run into memory problem... since you have to generate the entire Hamiltonian matrix  and manipulate it. Whereas qasm simulator allows you to do this faster by not generating the entire Hamiltonian matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure that the last paragraph is correct. I'm not aware of any difference between the simulators in the generation of the Hamitonian.