# Why is the local qasm_simulator significantly slower than the statevector_simulator?

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I've been running VQE experiments locally using both the `statevector_simulator` and `qasm_simulator`, however I've noticed that the runtimes for the `qasm_simulator` are significantly longer than that of `statevector_simulator`. According to [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13931/12248) the `statevector_simulator` produces ideal/deterministic results, whereas `qasm_simulator` produces non-ideal/probabilistic results. However I don't see why the simulation times should differ significantly($>\times 100$) if the number of `shots=1` for the `qasm_simulator` even if a `NoiseModel` or `measurement_error_mitigation_cls=CompleteMeasFitter` is used.

Is this in fact expected and how is it explained?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you use qasm_simulator with shots=1, this doesn't tell you anything! Unless IBM automatically switch your simulator to statevector_simulator if you specify the shots =1 when calling qasm_simulator.

Now in term of add noise model and doing measurement_error_mitigation. To be able to do this, you need to generate $2^n$ basis states and measure each of them to create a calibration matrix. It is an expensive procedure since you have many more quantum circuits to execute. Each circuit requires a certain amount of shots, up to 8192 shots. In statevector_simulator, you don't need to do this as there is no noise.